# Extract value from Json format in C#

Tags: c#, json, list, json-deserialization

I am trying to extract the **objectId** and **displayName** from below JSON format http result. But I have not been successful at all. can someone suggest me to extract **objectId** and **displayName**.

My code so far:

```html
 var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/")
};
string URI = $"/{TenantID}/users?$filter=userPrincipalName%20eq%20'{EmailAddress}'&api-version=1.6";
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + MSGraphToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI).ConfigureAwait(false);
var HttpsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(HttpsResponse);
UserDetails UserDetailsList = new UserDetails();
dynamic OdataResult = Result["value"];

if (Result != null)
{
    UserDetailsList.DisplayName = OdataResult.displayName ?? "N/A";
    UserDetailsList.ObjectID = OdataResult.objectId ?? "N/A";
}
return UserDetailsList;
```

JSON result:

```
{{
      "value": [
        {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
          "objectType": "User",
          "objectId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "assignedPlans": [
            {
              "assignedTimestamp": "2022-09-06T20:38:49Z",
              "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
              "service": "RMSOnline",
              "servicePlanId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            },
            {
              "assignedTimestamp": "2022-09-06T20:38:49Z",
              "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
              "service": "Adallom",
              "servicePlanId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            },        
          ],
          "displayName": "Sachin Tendulkar (alt_sachint)",
          "employeeId": "000000",          
          "userPrincipalName": "alt_sachint@pme.gbl.msidentity.com"
        }
      ]
    }}
```

Comment: Value is an array but you are trying to access properties like it were a single object

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to extract objectID from value array.

Comment: Why are you using 'dynamic' and not a typed object?

Comment: @Vinny is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes. it was resolved yesterday. I forgot to come back and mark the answer. I just did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use Parse if you only need to get a couple of values. In this case you don't need to create classes

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var value = JObject.Parse(json)["value"];
string objectId = (string)value[0]["objectId"]; // 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
string displayName = (string)value[0]["displayName"]; // Sachin Tendulkar (alt_sachint)
```

and remove an extra "{ }" from  the edges of your json

Answer (score 1):

First of all your posted JSON is invalid, I have corrected it.

```
{
    "value": [{
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
        "objectType": "User",
        "objectId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "assignedPlans": [{
                "assignedTimestamp": "2022-09-06T20:38:49Z",
                "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
                "service": "RMSOnline",
                "servicePlanId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            },
            {
                "assignedTimestamp": "2022-09-06T20:38:49Z",
                "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
                "service": "Adallom",
                "servicePlanId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            }
        ],
        "displayName": "Sachin Tendulkar (alt_sachint)",
        "employeeId": "000000",
        "userPrincipalName": "alt_sachint@pme.gbl.msidentity.com"
    }]

}
```

Then you should deserialize the json to a class object.

```
Root obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class AssignedPlan
{
    public DateTime assignedTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string capabilityStatus { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    public string servicePlanId { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.type")]
    public string odatatype { get; set; }
    public string objectType { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public List<AssignedPlan> assignedPlans { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string employeeId { get; set; }
    public string userPrincipalName { get; set; }
}
```

So you can get the List of Value by `obj.value` which is a List of `Value`. Value class has properties `objectId` and `employeeId` .

You can use `foreach` or `for` or LINQ to fetch these properties accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can get using dynamic also but i recommended to use strong type

Logic to get values

`Using Strong Type`

```
 private void ReadJson()
        {
            string json = @"{""value"":[{""odata.type"":""Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"",""objectType"":""User"",""objectId"":""00000000 - 0000 - 0000 - 0000 - 000000000000"",""assignedPlans"":[{""assignedTimestamp"":""2022 - 09 - 06T20: 38:49Z"",""capabilityStatus"":""Enabled"",""service"":""RMSOnline"",""servicePlanId"":""00000000 - 0000 - 0000 - 0000 - 000000000000""},{""assignedTimestamp"":""2022 - 09 - 06T20: 38:49Z"",""capabilityStatus"":""Enabled"",""service"":""Adallom"",""servicePlanId"":""00000000 - 0000 - 0000 - 0000 - 000000000000""},],""displayName"":""Sachin Tendulkar(alt_sachint)"",""employeeId"":""000000"",""userPrincipalName"":""alt_sachint @pme.gbl.msidentity.com""}]}";
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);

            var objid = response.value[0].objectId;
            var displayname = response.value[0].displayName;

            // using for loop 

            foreach( var res in response.value)
            {
                objid = res.objectId;
                displayname = res.displayName;
            }

            // you can use linq if you need object id and display name for specific condition

            
        }
```

Classes

```
public class Result
    {
        public List<Response> value { get; set; }
    }

public class Response
    {
        public string objectId { get; set; }

        public string displayName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("odata.type")]
        public string odatatype { get; set; }

        public string objectType { get; set; }

        public List<AssignedPlan> assignedPlans { get; set; }

        public string employeeId { get; set; }

        public string userPrincipalName { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssignedPlan
    {
        public DateTime assignedTimestamp { get; set; }
        public string capabilityStatus { get; set; }
        public string service { get; set; }
        public string servicePlanId { get; set; }
    }
```

`using dynamic`

```
// 2. using dynamic
            dynamic Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
            JArray jsonObject = JArray.FromObject(Result["value"]);
            //JArray jsonObject = JArray.Parse(Result["value"]);
            foreach (JObject content in jsonObject.Children<JObject>())
            {
                // you can get value from one of the approach
                // 1. Approach
                foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties().Where(p => p.Name == "objectId"))
                {
                    objid = prop.Value.ToString();
                }

                foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties().Where(p => p.Name == "displayName"))
                {
                    displayname = prop.Value.ToString();
                }

                // 2. Apprach
                foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
                {
                    if (prop.Name == "objectId")
                    {
                        objid = prop.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(prop.Name == "displayName")
                    {
                        displayname = prop.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }

            }
```

you can get value by following @Serge answer using dynamic if it is always one object in response(value node) but as per your sample it is array so you need to use Jarray or loop to get each value.